# Same code on two different Azure Servers, but one is having routing problems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have just deployed a webapp to two different Azure servers. One for Testing, an other for Production. The Testing server works fine, I load the main index page, then when I navigate to a details page it is okay. When I try on the Production server I get blank page and in the eventLog.xml I get errors leading me to believe it is a routing problem not finding my view for this page:

> at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

However as I mentioned it works on the test server, and also when debugging locally.

These webapps point to different databases, but the databases are accessible with SSMS and there appears to be no problem there.

Any advice would be appreciated. This is what the routing code set up for both looks like:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: I tried to find some route debugger tools, but the links were either dead, or nugget didn't want to find anything: Install-Package WebApiRouteDebugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a series of back end problems related to our database for prod not representing the development and test databases. This was causing loading parts of the webapp to fail in the background.

The view problem was just brought to my attention as a cascading consequence of the database missmatch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try attach debugger in this production webapp

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/